# Presto insert value in to a column of (array<struct<pos:int, date:string>>)

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a column 'col2' which is of type

`array<struct<pos:int, date:string>>`

I need to check if the column is empty and then insert values to the column and then unnest the values in the column

`case WHEN CARDINALITY(col2) = 0 THEN ARRAY[(0,'value1'),(0,'value2')]  else col2  end as col2`

Below is sql

```
WITH CTE AS 
    (SELECT 
        col1,
        case 
          WHEN CARDINALITY(col2) = 0 THEN ARRAY[(0,'value1'),(0,'value2')]
          else col2
        end as col2
        FROM table1
)
    SELECT 
    col1
    column2.value1 AS pos,
    column2.value2 AS date,
FROM CTE
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(col2) AS t(column2)
```

Because the case expression returns [{field1=1,field2=2020-03-01},{field1=1,field2=2020-01-09}]
i am not able to unpack it as value1 and value2, and above expression throws error.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

When the elements of an array are of type `row`, `UNNEST` expands them into separate columns. You need to adjust the `UNNEST` clause to reflect this.

Here's an example (tested with Trino 351, [formerly known as Presto SQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)):

```
WITH
data(entries) AS (VALUES
    ARRAY[],
    ARRAY[(1,'x'),(2,'y')]
),
cte(entries) AS (
    SELECT if(cardinality(entries) = 0, ARRAY[(0,'value1'),(0,'value2')], entries)
    FROM data
)
SELECT pos, date
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(entries) AS t(pos, date)
```